# How to tell macos proxy settings that the proxy is HTTPS server instead of HTTP?

Tags: macos, pac

I set up a HTTPS proxy server and use macos system proxy settings to set to localhost:8080. However the system seems keeping sending HTTP requests to the proxy and the TLS throws errors.

I guess that Macos by default forward original request with a new HTTP request to the proxy. How can I tell the system to use HTTPS instead of HTTP?

In pac file or other APIs the proxy option usually contains only `host` and `port`, so how does the client know it is a `HTTP` or `HTTPS` host?

Comment: Which protocol did you select in "Select a protocol to configure?"

Comment: This might belong to https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @joelfischerr Both HTTP & HTTPS. The thing is I tried to create a node HTTP proxy and both protocols connected to it and works just fine. When I switch node to HTTPS it keeps complaining receiving HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that system only support port 443 when the server is SSL based. Other ports than 443 won't handshake correctly in my case.

Comment: But you can specify a port in the system settings. If it then doesn't use the port you have set, you might have found a bug.

Comment: port is not necessarily always the same. A HTTP server can listen on 443 and HTTPS server can listen on 80 as well. So port itself is not a strong evidence.